# how to create folder recursively

Tags: sed, directory

there are two file path .

now i am in eee folder

```
/Volumes/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/text.txt
```

1) i am going to mv text.txt file to below path

```
/Volumes/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd_1/eee/text.txt  
or just create folder structure only
/Volumes/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd_1/eee/
```

with below command with recursively ,  but not works all

there are some solution related with this . 
but not works .

```
mkdir -p  $(`pwd | sed 's/ddd/ddd_l/'`)
or 
rsync -av -f"+ */" -f"- *" "$pwd" "$(`pwd | sed 's/ddd/ddd_l/'`)"
or 
mv test.MTS `pwd | sed 's/ddd/ddd_l/'`
or 
cp -R test.MTS `pwd | sed 's/ddd/ddd_l/'`
```

who can do this ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Why can't you just do `mv text.txt /Volumes/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd_1/eee/text.txt`?

Comment: because of there is no "eee" directory , i just want to folder path replace to ddd_1 and create folder all recursively .  but this is not allowed.

logically , i have no idea why won't be created sub folder all ? 
by  bellow command 

cp -R test.MTS `pwd | sed 's/test_source/test_target/'` 

if this works then  always files  can be moved or copied recursively 
by mirrored another structured folder somewhere .

Comment: There are no folders in UNIX - that's a WIndows term and the equivalent UNIX term is "directory". So what you want to do is MaKe and DIRectory - the tool to do that has the very obvious name of `mkdir` and the argument to make the directories recursively is `-p`. So what you need to do is `mkdir -p /Volumes/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd_1/eee && mv text.txt /Volumes/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd_1/eee`. If that's not all you need then update your question to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_file="/Volumes/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/text.txt"
mkdir -p "$(dirname "$new_file")"
touch "$new_file"
```